# YouTube API hosting unlisted videos for website using OAuth2.

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I need to host videos with a service like YouTube that allows some sort of privacy so that its not accessible easily to the public (or not at all).

I am using the YouTube API V3.

What I would like to achieve is to use one account to retrieve all the unlisted / private videos for that channel specified.

At the moment when I use:

```
$youtube_service->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet,id',array('channelId'=>'CHANNEL_ID'));
```

This will only retrieve public videos.

Is there a way I can authorize a specific user pro-grammatically and retrieve that users private or unlisted content/videos/playlists from the youtube API and populate my website?

Thanks in advance

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube API only supports public API key access and [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) access.  If you want to see a users private YouTube videos they will have to authenticate your application first using Oauth2, then you can save the refresh token and be able to access it at a later date.

Comment: Thanks could you elaborate on how to achieve this? how would they authenticate my application? how would I gain a refresh token? Then use that to access the content at a later date?

Comment: You should be able to find that info by Googleing Oauth2 and PHP https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php If you have any problems create a new question with your code.  We are hear to help you fix issues with your code not Google things and code it for you.

Comment: I have not asked you to code nor have I asked you to google. I am asking for the theory / pseudo code and if its possible, as I see no way with my research to achieve this hence asking my question.  I have my application working but only with public videos.

Comment: The link I just posted is the example directly from The Google php client library on how to use Oauth2 with php does it works.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I am currently using that library and yes it does work but I am not sure about accessing private content and using the refresh token, Its a lack of understanding on my behalf.

Comment: then create a new question about Saving refreshtoken with PHP. Your current question isnt PHP related its "Is there a way I can authorize a specific user pro-grammatically and retrieve that users private or unlisted content/videos/playlists from the YouTube API and populate my website?"   Which I answered with if you use Oauth2 have the user Authencate your application then save the refresh token you will be able to access there information at a later date programticly.

Comment: OK thank you I shall accept this and create a new question.

Comment: Tip:   $client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken

Comment: here is my new question :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247907/authorize-a-specific-user-pro-grammatically-and-retrieve-that-users-private-or-u